# Progressbar tag Animation not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, animation, progress-bar

I'm using slideIn animation for my progressbar. It works correctly by Firefox but somehow it stops working in Chrome.

My progress tag that im using in HTML is:

```
<progress class="progress-slideIn" 
          style="height: 6px;
                        /* animation trigger */
                        /* ignored in IE 11 */
                        --animation-delay: {{ loop.index**1.5 / 3.4 }}s;

                        /* hide animated bar */
                        overflow: hidden;

                        /* remove progress styling */
                        -webkit-appearance: none;
                        appearance: none;
                    " value="20" max="50">
ProgressBar</progress>
```

In CSS I decalred a class for animation and styling for specific browsers (Chrome & Firefox) and one keyframe for both of them:

```
.progress-slideIn::-webkit-progress-value {
    animation: 2s progress-slideIn;

    /* inherit delay per element */
      animation-delay: var(--animation-delay);
    /* initial state */
      transform: translateX(-100%); 
    /* keep final state */
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.progress-slideIn::-moz-progress-bar {
    animation: 2s progress-slideIn;

    /* inherit delay per element */
      animation-delay: var(--animation-delay);
    /* initial state */
      transform: translateX(-100%);
    /* keep final state */
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}
@keyframes progress-slideIn {
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```